# Android - keytool XML signing/verification

Tags: android

Is it necessary to create both (private and public keys) via keytool utility? Is the private key created by "-protected" added when exporting keystore by keytool? If I have now private and public keys, how to make initial signing process and verification of some, e.g. external XML document?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following the [android keytool tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert), it shouldn't create multiple keys it should create a single .keystore file.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore 
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

you shouldn't be getting a private&pub key

Comment: yea, this is for generating keytool, but I will sign XML which will be on the web, and when I download it via HTTPurlconnection, I have to check if its my desired XML file, so here i need to check it. Up to now, I have keys, i have certificates but i don't know how to sign XML or verify it later

Comment: you are trying to verify that a XML file that you downloaded from the web will be the right XML file? you can store a md5 sum in your app/web and then verify the download with the hash.

If you are talking about XML-Sig then you need to open the XML and verify the signature manually using SAX.

Comment: manually? you would then need to be able to handle `<SignatureMethod Algorithm>` properly, such as sha-1 and then be able to calculate that and compare that against a stored key on your application.